# How to connect a child item in a tree-structure visualization with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a list of items and sub items that are connected with lines.

So far I have done this -

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li.item span {
  position: relative;
}

ul.sub-menu li.item span::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li class="items">Task 1</li>

  <li class="items">Task 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="item"><span>Sub Task 1</span></li>

      <li class="item"><span>Sub Task 2</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="item"><span>Sub Task 1</span></li>
          <li class="item"><span>Sub Task 2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="item"><span>Sub Task 3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="items">Task 3</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, `Sub Task 3` is not fully connected with its parent. How to  connect this?

**Note:** I saw a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707144/css-html-sub-list-items-lines-connected-to-parent/63707529) and gave this as an answer. Then I saw this problem was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it differently like below:

```css
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.item::before,
.item::after,
.item:last-child .sub-menu::before{
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;

}
.item::before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: -10px;
}

.item::after {
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0.6em;
  top: 1.2em;
  width: 1px;
}
/* the bekow will avoid the line to go down if there is no sub task (not transparent!)*/
.item:last-child > .sub-menu::before {
  top: calc(0.6em - 1px);
  width: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  left: -12px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li class="item">Task 1</li>

  <li class="item">Task 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="item">Sub Task 1</li>

      <li class="item">Sub Task 2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="item">Sub Task 1</li>
          <li class="item">Sub Task 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="item">Sub Task 3
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="item">Sub Task 1</li>
          <li class="item">Sub Task 2
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="item">Sub Task 1</li>
              <li class="item">Sub Task 2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item">Sub Task 3</li>
          <li class="item">Sub Task 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="item">Task 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh... thank you. I never thought to divide horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul made an update to rectify the code in order to cover all the cases