# Treeview design ideas

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview

So I've made a html treeview the same way as the example shown later, and I'm wondering if someone had an idea on how to make a more readable/user friendly design for it?
I don't need a solution on how to make the perfect design, just some ideas, or links to some usefull guides on how to make this look better.

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
ul, #myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret">Item 1</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Sub item 1.1</li>
      <li>Sub item 1.2</li>
      <li><span class="caret">Sub item 1.3</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Sub item 1.1.1</li>
          <li>Sub item 1.1.2</li>
          <li><span class="caret">Sub item 1.1.1.1</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Sub item 1.1.1.1.1</li>
              <li>Sub item 1.1.1.1.2</li>
              <li>Sub item 1.1.1.1.3</li>
              <li>Sub item 1.1.1.1.4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to make it look somthing like this picture?

[image: Treeview example]

Comment: I faced ***kind of*** a similar issue. You can refer to the answer of this question for the design. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721158/how-to-connect-a-child-item-in-a-tree-structure-visualization-with-css

Comment: This could be an example how you can created a styled tree: https://gist.github.com/dylancwood/7368914